# Rails 4 How to access model attributes in instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into a seemingly simple problem, but I can't figure out what the problem is. I'm building an API using Rails 4.

I have a model called Constant

```
class Constant < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.calcuate_something(a, b, c, d, e)
    self.number_one + self.number_two + (self.number_three*a) + (self.number_four*b) + (self.number_five*c) + (self.number_six*d) + (self.number_seven*e)
  end

end
```

This model has attributes `number_one`, `number_two`, `number_three`, `number_four`, `number_five`, `number_six`, and `number_seven`.

In my controller, I'm doing this:

```
@constant = Constant.find_by_id(params[:id])
number = @constant.calculate_something(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

And then I get an error that says `NoMethodError (undefined method 'number_one' for #<Class:0x007fd3d4466068>):`. I'm not trying to access a method called `number_one`, I'm trying to find the field in the model.

I've verified that there is a column called `number_one` for all of my entries and that every single entry has a value. Is there something wrong with my syntax or setup??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your definition of `self.calculate_something(a, b, c, d, e)`. Using the keyword `self` is actually creating a class method instead of an instance method, and therefore doesn't have access to those attributes.

Try refactoring it to `def calculate_something(a, b, c, d, e)`

Update from comments:

The second issues is `@constant` is being assigned to the ActiveRecord_Relation generated by `Constant.find_by_id(params[:id])` instead of the record instance since rails doesn't automatically evaluate queries until necessary. This can be fixed by changing `find_by_id` to `find`, or force the query to execute by `Constant.find_by_id(params[:id]).first`. Personally, I like changing to `find` as you know the specific record you want.

Comment: But then when I do that, I get a NoMethodError for `calculate_something`. More specifically, it looks like this `NoMethodError (undefined method 'number_one' for #<Constant::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd3d43fec88>):`. Why is this happening??

Comment: ahh, doing `find_by_id` is returning a result set, which is the `ActiveRecord_Relation` part. Change `find_by_id` to `find`, or change the statement to `Constant.find_by_id(params[:id]).first`

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Class and Instance Methods in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/), you want to define method for object as instance method without `self.`:

```
def calculate_something(a, b, c, d, e)
```

But, if you want to define class method, so you need to use `self`.

Don't use `find_by_id`, you need to use `find` as the following:

```
@constant = Constant.find(params[:id])
```